# Ошибка google is not defined

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api

При вызове функции `initMap()`, которая загружает карту выдаёт ошибку

`google is not defined.`

функция:

```
function initMap(lat, lng, radius) {
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng);
    map = new google.maps.Map($("#map"), {
        center: myLatlng,
        zoom: 10,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });
        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            strokeColor: '#FF0000',
            strokeOpacity: 0.8,
            strokeWeight: 2,
            fillColor: '#FF0000',
            fillOpacity: 0.35,
            map: map,
            center: myLatlng,
            radius: radius,
            editable: true

        });

    google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'radius_changed', function() {
        $("#radius").attr("value", circle.getRadius() * 0.001);
    });

    google.maps.event.addListener(circle, 'center_changed', function() {
        $("#google_lat").attr("value", parseFloat(circle.getCenter().lat()));
        $("#google_lng").attr("value", parseFloat(circle.getCenter().lng()));
        $("#lat_out").html(circle.getCenter().lat());
        $("#lng_out").html(circle.getCenter().lng());
    });


    $("#radius").keyup(function(){
        temp_radius = parseFloat(($(this).val()) * 1000);
        circle.setRadius(temp_radius);
    });

    $("#radius").ready(function(){
        $("#radius").val(5);
    });

    $('#apply').click(function () {
        $("#wrap_for_map").attr('hidden', true);
        $("#google_lat").val(parseFloat(circle.getCenter().lat()));
        $("#google_lng").val(parseFloat(circle.getCenter().lng()));
        $("#google_radius").val(parseFloat(circle.radius));
    });

    $('#cancel').click(function cancel() {
        $("#wrap_for_map").attr('hidden', true);
        $("#google_lat").val(null);
        $("#google_lng").val(null);
        $("#radius").val(null);
        $("#google_radius").val(null)
        $('#lat_out').html('');
        $('#lng_out').html('');
    });
}
```

вызывается первый раз при загрузке страницы:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var google_lat = $("#google_lat").val();
    var google_lng = $("#google_lng").val();
    initMap(google_lat, google_lng, temp_radius);
```

Comment: подключена ли сама библиотека? есть ли другие ошибки в консоли?

Comment: Включаешь через <script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>  ?

Comment: ещё выдаёт ошибку TypeError: Argument 1 of Window.getComputedStyle does not implement interface Element.

Comment: подключаю через <script async defer  type="text/javascript"
   src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=key&callback=initMap">
 </script>

Comment: а разве эта функция принимает jQuery объект? `new google.maps.Map`

Answer (score 1):

> а разве эта функция принимает jQuery объект? new google.maps.Map – Grundy 4 минуты назад

Да, действительно ошибка была из за этого
исправил на `map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"),` и заработало